# c# xml xpath SelectSingleNode attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can I get the value of attribute:

`/Document/Setup/Info/Att/Group[6]/Attr[5]@value`

I've tried

```
String S = nest.SelectSingleNode("./osis:Info/osis:Att/osis:Group[6]>osis:Attr[5]@value).Value;
```

The following works for the `FilePath`:

```
String F = nest.SelectSingleNode("./osis:Info/osis:FilePath", >xmlns).Value;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="http://www.ns.com/ns/ns">
  <Setup>
    <Info>
      <FilePath>\\computer1\project\E2002307\E2002307.drg</FilePath>
      <Att>
        <Group class="custom" name="Manu" desc="attributes"
            ord="6">
          <Attr num="119" name="xyz" desc="zyx" type="s" ord="1" value="S355">
            <Valid perm="e" max="100"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="120" name="thick" desc="thick." type="r" ord="2" value="5">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0" max="99999"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="121" name="units" desc="units." type="s" ord="4" value="mm">
            <Valid perm="e" expr="mm" max="80"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="123" name="time" desc="minutes." type="r" ord="24">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="124" name="X" desc="X direction." type="r" ord="11" value="3">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
          <Attr num="125" name="Y" desc="Y direction." type="r" ord="12" value="1">
            <Valid perm="e" min="0"/>
          </Attr>
        </Group>
```

Comment: Can you show the xml?

Comment: @Oluwafemi I've added as much XML as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the context node is `<Setup>`, then the correct XPath to get `value` attribute of the fifth `<Att>` under the sixth `<Group>` would be as follow :

```
./osis:Info/osis:Att/osis:Group[6]/osis:Attr[5]/@value
```

Side note: In most case, element indices aren't reliable for finding the corresponding element. You may want to filter by attributes value instead, f.e by saying *"find `<Attr>` element having attribute `name` equals `X`"* : `/Attr[@name='X']`

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly.  I'll have a look at filtering by attributes next.

Comment: what if the Value is null for example above in this instance time has no value.